CSS not reflecting in the HTML page
I have been doing the html first and the css last. Now in this part, I was trying to edit the css but it doesn't reflect. I suspect it has something to do with how I arranged the links but my site.css is in the top priority for the css but still it doesn't change anything in my design
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/27.1.48/material.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/7.0.5/signalr.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/27.1.48/dist/ej2.min.js"></script>

I would like to ask if something is wrong with this.
Im trying to edit this
<a asp-page="/Profile" asp-route-IsEditable="true" class="edit-btn">Edit</a>

and this is the css
.edit-btn  {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

I need help with this part because it is really not reflecting in the page.

Things to try: use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see whether the css file has been found or not. If not, correct the filepath. If the css is loading but not changing then clear cache as your browser may be picking up an old version.

This question is similar to: Absolute paths for CSS files in ASP.net. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You may be experiencing that a different selector overrides yours (if your CSS is loading). See MDN docs: CSS Specificity. Use your browser developer tools. You will see which style overrides yours. Just choose a more specific CSS selector.

This is happening cause the css files path is relative to your page.  And not to the base path as it should.
You can fix it by adding
<base href="~/"> in your layout page _layout.cshtml before the <head> tag.

Hello, i would like to ask what exactly I should do to give a relative path. This is a razor pages asp net core project. Thank you for answering

@Adi Hey, you did not mentioned it earlier.  I have updated my answers.
